# Send widgets content scaled to printer

Tags: python, qt, printing, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using `QWidget.grab` to get a pixmap containing what a component currently displays. It works perfectly apart from the size of the component not suitable for my printing requirements.

Is there a way so I can grab the pixmap of the component in a particular size?

Comment: Provide some code. If you ask like this answering the question is not quite feasible.

Answer (score 1):

`QPixMap.grab()` in Qt5 and `QPixMap.grabWidget()` in Qt4 get a pixmap of a painted widget in the screen resolution which is the natural painting resolution. Using the rectangle parameter you can even get parts of widgets.

The natural output resolution is the widgets own screen resolution. But afterwards you can scale it to anything you like via `QPixMap.scaled()` so that it fits your printing requirements.

It would actually be nice to change (simple scale) the painting resolution when grabing. But I don't know of any way to achieve this.

Comment: `QPixmap.grabWidget` was replaced with `QWidget.grab` in PyQt5.